# I get a EADDRINUSE error when I try to start a node.js server on OpenShift

Tags: node.js, openshift

So, I successfully commited a node.js app to OpenShift - without getting any error - but it does not work (error 503 when trying to access it through my browser, connection timeout when running tests against it from my local machine). The output when commiting says that node and mysql start successfully, and that the build succeeded.

I accessed the server through ssh, and checked the node log. It says an EADDRINUSE occured: `Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8080`.

In my configuration, I use:

```
"server":{
    "host":"OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP",
    "port":"OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT"
}
```

I also checked available environement variables in the shell with `export` and both are there, and 8080 is the right port.

When running `ps` in the shell, it does show only the programs `ps` and `bash` running. `EADDRINUSE` should mean that the port is already in use by another program, but I don't see anything running... I can't run `netstat` (permission denied).

I tried various combinations of stop/start/restart, but I always get the same error.

I am pretty lost at this point. Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you able to get port 8080 if you just use netcat? `netcat-l 8080`

Comment: Also, if 8080 is busy, maybe try telnetting to it and seeing if you can figure out what's on it if it's not your node process

Comment: The netcat command is not available. Also, I don't think I have access via telnet. I just have a ssh access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Locally, I used to start the server with `app.listen(port);`, which is enough to run it and access it on `localhost`. But that does not work on OpenShift. The host needs to be specified too: `app.listen(port, host);`.